# How can I break a single list into multiple columns semantically?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, html-lists

The current approach our site is using to break a single list into multiple columns is to use multiple `ul`s:

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
</ul>
```

This doesn't seem ideal to me, since semantically, it's not two lists, it's one. I've seen a lot of inadequate solutions for multi-columns lists. I'm looking for a solution that:

1. Uses the following markup structure

   ```
   <ul>
     <li>one</li>
     <li>two</li>
     <li>three</li>
     <li>four</li>
   </ul>
   ```
2. Organizes like this:

   ```
   one    three
   two    four
   ```

   Not this:

   ```
   one    two
   three  four
   ```
3. Works without modification if list-length changes, or if items wrap multiple lines.
4. Uses valid, semantic HTML.
5. Works down to IE8.

The ideal solution is CSS only, but I'm open to using jQuery UI or light-weight Javascript.

(PS, [here's my CSS attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/brentonstrine/hH53F/), with notable problems.)

Edit: This question is specific to *semantic* lists. The other supposedly "duplicate" question is regarding `<div>` elements, which is a different ballgame because additional markup is allowed. No additional markup is allowed between a `<ul>` and an `<li>`. This question is focused on *semantics* which means there is an emphasis on using HTML to indicate with as much detail as possible the meaning of the content.

Comment: CSS only would be difficult as you'll need to know which ones to float left and which ones to float right, however with js all you'd have to do is add one class to the first half of them and another class to the second half, one floating left the other floating right.

Comment: you can use nth child selectors like odd and even, but it wouldn't work in IE8

Comment: @BrianGlaz odd/even would result in `one two` on row one and `three four` on row two rather than the intended `one three` and `two four`

Comment: Honestly, @cimmanon `DIV`s are a whole different ballgame. You don't have the semantic limitations that you have in lists. Multi-column lists are a specific issue, in fact, [alistapart has an entire article](http://alistapart.com/article/multicolumnlists) on the topic.

Comment: @brentonstrine No, there's no difference between a ul and a div when it comes to any solution (CSS or JavaScript).  If you want IE8 support, you've effectively eliminated all pure CSS options.

Comment: @cimmanon With `DIV`s, there are some fairly simple solutions involving adding extra markup. Doing that within a list would create invalid HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question, but I think I got a CSS only solution.

[Here it is on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brentonstrine/hH53F/3/).

Basically, I use the general sibling selector (This symbol: `~`, works [in IE7](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/#t12) too!) to highlight all elements after the breakpoint, and move them over and up. As long as you set a line-height, seems to work cross browser down to IE7.

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li class="newline">three</li>
  <li>four</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.newrow,
.newrow ~ li {
    margin-left: 120px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

Am I missing anything obvious here?

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing this, it's a cool idea. Question - how to do three columns?

Comment: Just do `class=col2` and `class=col3` where you want the column breaks to start. Then make the CSS same as what I have but for `col3` it's `margin-left: 240px`.

Comment: [Here's a JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hH53F/20/) to explain better. Basically `.col2,.col2~li{margin-left:270px; margin-top:-220px; margin-bottom:220px;}`

Comment: Hi, I commented out the indentation rules, and now there is an extra line at the top of column three - any way to avoid this? Thanks, I appreciate the help

Comment: Ok, I put some different data in there and the "problem" seems to have gone away; maybe you know the reason this happened though – I don't know what happened

Answer (score 6):

You could use columns for browsers that support it

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/eaewX/33/

Here is a jQuery example for full browser support

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/MKL4g/131/

```
var postsArr = new Array(),
    $postsList = $('ul.posts');

//Create array of all posts in lists
$postsList.find('li').each(function(){
    postsArr.push($(this).html());
})

//Split the array at this point. The original array is altered.
var firstList = postsArr.splice(0, Math.round(postsArr.length / 2)),
    secondList = postsArr,
    ListHTML = '';

function createHTML(list){
    ListHTML = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        ListHTML += '<li>' + list[i] + '</li>'
    };
}

//Generate HTML for first list
createHTML(firstList);
$postsList.html(ListHTML);

//Generate HTML for second list
createHTML(secondList);
//Create new list after original one
$postsList.after('<ul class="posts"></ul>').next().html(ListHTML);
```

Comment: great jQuery approach.  Instead of trying to figure out what to divide by, the JavaScript does it for you. plus everything falls back to a single list if JavaScript is disabled, and it folds if the window is thin. - thanks for sharing!

Comment: Hi Vector, I will be using your code and modifying it to achieve a similar task.  Thank you for posting.  I am fuzzy on the legalities and such so I will also link to this answer in my code.  Please let me know if you have any objections.

Answer (score 3):

The "correct" way to do this would be to use CSS3 columns:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts
- http://davidwalsh.name/css-columns

But that will only get you to IE10.

I would recommend going that route and then using IE shims and javascript o handle IE9 and IE8. I forget, but modernizr might provide a shim for helping you out.

Comment: Where's the code?  If those links go down, this answer will be useless to future users.

Answer (score 2):

[CSS Columns](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_columns.asp) is the best solution but doesn't work for older browsers. You could use [nth-child](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/) to do something close, but you wont get a split list (you also need a polyfill to use it in older browsers). The easiest solution would probably be a javascript one - it will split the lists but also leave your code clean. Here is a function for turning lists into any number of columns.

http://jsfiddle.net/UrH69/

**SCRIPT**

```
$.fn.extend({
    list2Columns: function(numCols) {
        var listItems = $(this).find('li'); /* get the list data */
        var listHeader = $(this);
        var numListItems = listItems.length;
        var numItemsPerCol = Math.ceil(numListItems / numCols); /* divide by the number of columns requires */
        var currentColNum = 1, currentItemNumber = 1, returnHtml = '', i = 0;

        /* append the columns */
        for (i=1;i<=numCols;i++) {
            $(this).parent().append('<ul class="column list-column-' + i + '"></ul>');
        }

        /* append the items to the columns */
        $.each(listItems, function (i, v)
        {    
            if (currentItemNumber <= numItemsPerCol){
                currentItemNumber ++;
            } else {
                currentItemNumber = 1;
                currentColNum ++;
            }
            $('.list-column-'+currentColNum).append(v);
        });
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

**USAGE**

```
$('ul').list2Columns(2); // Change this number to change num of columns
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>five</li>
  <li>six</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.column { float:left; }
```

Comment: You've got a good start, but it's not finished. This code will fail, eg., if you have multiple lists on one page.

Comment: True, but if you give the list an ID and target it directly that will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can use css column-count for that this demo works in chrome only but you can make it cross browser

http://jsfiddle.net/UuwKC/

```
ul {-webkit-column-count:2}
```